# call ResultSet.getMetaData in Scala results in java.lang.SecurityException

Tags: scala, jdbc, slick

I'm using Slick in Akka to access MySQL DB.
I want to get the table column info by calling `resultSet.getMetaData`, as shown below:
(I tried with `slick.jdbc.meta.MTable.getTables`, but it always returns an empty vector; as [someone else also ran into it.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50516061/scala-slick-mtable-gettables-return-empty-vector-list))

```scala
implicit val meta2string = GetResult{ row: PositionedResult =>
  val md = row.rs.getMetaData() // call rs.getMetaData will cause exception thrown
  "debugging"
}

val done  = Slick.source(sql"SELECT * FROM trips".as[String](meta2string)).runForeach(println)
```

The problem is, when ever I call `rs.getMetaData()`, an exception will occur:

```
java.lang.SecurityException: Prohibited package name: java.sql
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.preDefineClass(ClassLoader.java:898)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1014)
    at java.base/java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:174)
    at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:550)
    at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:458)
    at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:452)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:451)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:588)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:575)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
    at $line303.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$.$anonfun$meta2string$1(<pastie>:138)
    at slick.jdbc.GetResult$$anon$2.apply(GetResult.scala:73)
    at slick.jdbc.GetResult$$anon$2.apply(GetResult.scala:73)
    at slick.jdbc.SQLActionBuilder$$anon$1$$anon$2.extractValue(StaticQuery.scala:100)
    at slick.jdbc.StatementInvoker$$anon$2.extractValue(StatementInvoker.scala:67)
    at slick.jdbc.PositionedResultIterator.fetchNext(PositionedResult.scala:176)
    at slick.util.ReadAheadIterator.update(ReadAheadIterator.scala:28)
    at slick.util.ReadAheadIterator.hasNext(ReadAheadIterator.scala:34)
    at slick.util.ReadAheadIterator.hasNext$(ReadAheadIterator.scala:33)
    at slick.jdbc.PositionedResultIterator.hasNext(PositionedResult.scala:167)
    at slick.jdbc.StreamingInvokerAction.emitStream(StreamingInvokerAction.scala:31)
    at slick.jdbc.StreamingInvokerAction.emitStream$(StreamingInvokerAction.scala:26)
    at slick.jdbc.SQLActionBuilder$$anon$1.emitStream(StaticQuery.scala:95)
    at slick.jdbc.SQLActionBuilder$$anon$1.emitStream(StaticQuery.scala:95)
    at slick.basic.BasicBackend$DatabaseDef$$anon$4.run(BasicBackend.scala:342)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
```

I'm not sure if there's sth. wrong with my use, or it's not supported by Slick?
Could anyone please help me on this?

Comment: The error would seem to suggest that it is trying to load a class in package `java.sql`, but the thing being loaded is outside of the Java bootclasspath (eg a library has its own class in the package `java.sql`), which is no longer allowed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not quite sure of this, but I suspect this issue is due to that I was running the code example in sbt console.
I ran the same code snippet with a jar and everything was fine.